# how to see summary image of former steps in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard to visualize the image(CelebA) generated by dcgan
Specifically, I created a writer and image summary with:

```
tf.summary.image('generated', image_output)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir, graph)
summary = sess.run(summary_op)
```

after each 100 step I would add a image summary with:

```
writer.add_summary(image, step)
```

I think the event file of tensorboard save all the images generated at each step since the event file keeps growing larger. But when I run tensorboard I can only see the latest image. 
Is there any way to see the former images? Or they are not saved in the event file and I can't see them.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you have raised was common enough to warrant a [feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4721) several months ago that was rolled into TensorFlow 1.1.0.

A small sliding bar appears below each image summary in Tensorboard with which you can scroll through the summary steps if you upgrade to TensorFlow 1.1.0+.